# Instantiate new class instance inside Symfony services (Best practice)

Tags: php, symfony, service

In Symfony when I create a service and I need an instance of some classes, I pass them as parameter in service or I can create a new instance inside my functions service. I ask this because some Classes constructor needs parameters which I  don't have yet when passing the class as parameter.

Comment: In many cases you would use a factory for this sort of thing.  Define the factory as a service and inject it.  Then, when you need your service you would do something like:  $myService = $myServiceFactory->create($paginator);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you pass them as params in service. try to inject your deps to the max and not instantiate directly your services.

see SOLID development principle and particulary in this case Dependency Inversion Principle

[image]

Comment: But somes services  Constructor need parametres, like doctrine Paginator Class.

Comment: you can inject them also in your services.yml

Comment: doctrine Paginator Class need query parametre which i dont i have when passing the class as argument.

Comment: return the query from your service and not the results and paginate into your controller with your paginator